# C++ executing a shellcode from caesar cipher does not work

Tags: c++, winapi

In my code example, I hardcoded my shellcode, and execution works fine:

```
std::string(buffer) = "\x48\x31\xc9\x48\x81\xe9\xc6\xff\xff ..snip..";

PUINT8 shellcode = new UINT8[buffer.size()];
RtlCopyMemory(shellcode, buffer.data(), buffer.size());

std::cout << shellcode;
// To DO
```

[image: Shellcode works fine]

In my second code example, I just added a Caesar cipher decoder with my shellcode encoded as a string in `buffer`, however I am not sure why it is being processed differently if it's stored in my `buffer` as a string/byte array just like in the first code example?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    std::string(buffer) = "_{7;_{64_{f<_{7;_{;4_{h<_{f9_{ii_{ii_{ii_";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++)
        buffer[i] -= 3;

    PUINT8 shellcode = new UINT8[buffer.size()];

    RtlCopyMemory(shellcode, buffer.data(), buffer.size());

    std::cout << shellcode;
    delete[] shellcode;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Prints differently]

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] as required here!

Comment: you have it right there! ^^ @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: I don't think so, read the linked article again please!

Comment: full code is there now @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Great improvement

Comment: The bug is in your Ceasar's cipher code. Since we cannot see that code, there's little we can do to fix the bug. A [mcve] would remedy this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Caesar-decoded shellcode does not match your hard-coded shellcode, that is why you are getting different outputs.

Let's look at the first character as an example, but this applies to the whole data as a whole:

Your Caesar-encoded string begins with the ASCII `_` character, which has a hex value of `0x5F`.  When decremented by 3, that becomes the hex value `0x5C`, which is the ASCII `\` character.

However, your hard-coded shellcode begins with the ASCII `H` character, which has a hex value of `0x48`. Whether you left-shift (decrement) that value by 3, or right-shift (increment) it by 3, the result won't come close to being near `0x5C` or `0x5F`.  Left-shifted, `0x48` will be `0x45` (`E`). Right-shifted, it will be `0x4B` (`K`).

Which means that your Caesar-encoded string is the wrong encoding of your desired shellcode to begin with.

Comment: thank you! It is really strange, but I think I was able to find the bad encoder based on your answer. One of them was shifting my chars and the new oncer was not doing the same process. I somehow got them mixed up in a process.